# Automating HTTP GET/POST in OSX

Tags: macos, http, osx-lion, automator

I need to release my IP address at the router on an hourly basis. The router page needs simple authentication and a button click to do the process. These are the HTTP calls:

Authenticate

```
GET /RST_st_dhcp.htm HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.10.1.1
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

Release button click

```
POST /st_dhcp.cgi?id=1044071018 HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.10.1.1
Content-Length: 31
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=
Origin: http://10.10.1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://10.10.1.1/RST_st_dhcp.htm
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

connect=Release&refreshScrn=yes
```

How can this be automated in OSX? Is it possible to write automator scripts for this?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use `curl` to make that request - something like

```
curl -e http://10.10.1.1/RST_st_dhcp.htm \
  -d 'connect=Release&refreshScrn=yes' -u user:password \
  'http://10.10.1.1/st_dhcp.cgi?id=1044071018'
```

You'll need to check whether the `id` in the URL matters. If not, the above should be all you  need. If it does then you may have to make the first request to get the `id` from its payload.